# why is laravel-stripe-webhooks signature invalid on production server, but same code works fine on local dev

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, laravel-6

I have implemented `laravel-stripe-webhooks` successfully in my Laravel 6 app and on my local dev copy can successfully process the payload back from Stripe Checkout. However, when I commit my app to my Forge production server, I get an invalid signature error and my app repots 500 back to Stripe.

I have checked and re-checked the Stripe live webhook secret key (not the Stripe CLI one) and it matches. The other possible reason I read for this is JSON parsing that changes the payload received and causes a mismatch that fails the signature verification. Since my code works fine on my dev server (using Stripe CLI) I can rule out JSON parsing as the issue, as that would exist also in the dev version and cause the same error there.

Here's the complete error I get from my Forge production app:

```
[2023-01-27 14:49:26] production.ERROR: The signature is invalid. {"exception":"[object] (Spatie\\WebhookClient\\Exceptions\\WebhookFailed(code: 0): The signature is invalid. at /home/forge/divorcesplit.com/vendor/spatie/laravel-webhook-client/src/Exceptions/WebhookFailed.php:11)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/spatie/laravel-webhook-client/src/WebhookProcessor.php(44): Spatie\\WebhookClient\\Exceptions\\WebhookFailed::invalidSignature()
#1 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/spatie/laravel-webhook-client/src/WebhookProcessor.php(28): Spatie\\WebhookClient\\WebhookProcessor->ensureValidSignature()
#2 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks/src/StripeWebhooksController.php(27): Spatie\\WebhookClient\\WebhookProcessor->process()
#3 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(48): Spatie\\StripeWebhooks\\StripeWebhooksController->__invoke(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), NULL)
#4 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(219): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Spatie\\StripeWebhooks\\StripeWebhooksController), '__invoke')
#5 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#6 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(681): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#7 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(32): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#12 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): App\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/AuthenticateSession.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\AuthenticateSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(56): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(683): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#25 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(624): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#27 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(613): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(170): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(145): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#42 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 /home/forge/mywebsite.com/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 {main}
"}
```

Any suggestions are very welcome because until I fic this I'm dead in the water and my app cannto process Stripe transactions.

Comment: Is your local development environment running the exact same code as the deployed server? Are you sure the endpoint secret is the correct one for the endpoint configured to receive the webhooks? If you checked all of that, then this might be an issue with the body parsing as you say. If this is not your code (ie, it's part of Laravel) you may need to contact the developers of that for guidance.

Comment: @NolanH, as far as I can tell both are running the same. I needed to do a composer install separately on the server for this as the automated syncing of packages between dev and production (using SourceTree) when I added `laravel-stripe-webhooks` caused Composer to run out of memory. Once I got that resolved it all worked, with the exception of the signature issue stopping my code from running any further processing the new customer accounts. SourceTree/Git seems to think they match, but I'm never sure about .gitnore and what gets excluded. Everything I can think to check is present.

Comment: Do you know if `laravel-stripe-webhooks` also loads Spatie's `laravel-webhook-client`? That got pulled into the mix and I'm not confident it is part of the `laravel-stripe-webhooks` package. Now I'm starting to wonder if it's conflicting with the signature verification.

Comment: I'd recommend logging the inputs to `constructEvent` to verify its the correct secret & original body. You can also manual calculate the expected signature using the documented algorithm:  https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures#verify-manually 
If you don't control the `constructEvent` code you'll need to work with the maintainer who does.

Comment: OMG!! I am such an idiot. I didn't change out the Stripe CLI secret key for the one provided in the Stripe dashboard for the specific webhook `<slapping forehead!>`. Thank you for all the help, and apologies for being an idiot. I lost a week debugging why this didn't work, and it did all along (if I had provided the correct secret key)